# Should custom Dojo widgets include a container

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

So I want to create a custom widget that has some forms fields in it.  I can't foresee a situation in which I need to reuse it outside of the single purpose I'm coding it for now.  I want the widget to appear inside a dijit Dialog.

That being said, is it better practice to have the Dialog part of the widget itself?  Or should I leave the widget in a "free form" HTML structure, able to be placed inside of anything?

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to the latter approach?

Comment: The worst I encounter is if I want to have a "cancel" button in the dialog, I have to resort to other methods such as the pub/sub system to close it, since the widget has no knowledge of it's container.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize the functionality of the Dialog widget, then it would be best practice to have your widget inherit from Dialog. However, if you just want a custom Form widget, then it would be better to leave your widget as its own module that can be used as a Dialog widget's `content` (or anywhere else you ever need it).